# Can't use flask-moment to show the time on webpage

Tags: python, html, flask

I want to use the Flask-moment to show the time on the web page when I visit the index.html
I've used the bootstrap up, and used the moment.js,but it still doesn't work.
Please give some help , thanks !

**my main py**

```
from flask.ext.bootstrap import Bootstrap
from flask.ext.moment import Moment
from flask import request
from datetime import datetime

app = Flask(__name__)
bootstrap=Bootstrap(app)
moment=Moment(app)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html',current_time=datetime.utcnow())
```

**This is my base.html which extends from the bootstrap**

```
{% extends "bootstrap/base.html" %}
{%block head%}
{{super()}}
<link rel='shortcut icon' href="{{url_for('static',filename='favicon.ico')}}" type='image/x-icon'>
<link rel='icon' href="{{url_for('static',filename='favicon.ico')}}" type="image/x-icon">
{% block scripts %}          #Here I use the bootstrap
{{ super() }}                 #But I dont' whether it works or not
{{ moment.include_moment() }}
{% endblock %}
{%endblock%}

{% block title %}Flasky{% endblock %}

{% block navbar %}
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle"
        data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
<a class="navbar-brand" href="/">Flasky</a>
    </div>
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
</div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
    <div class="container">
{% block page_content %}{% endblock %}
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

**The last is the index.html**

```
<p>The local date and time is {{moment(current_time).format('LLL')}}.</p>
<p>That was {{moment(current_time).fromNow(refresh=True)}}</p>
```

[image]

Comment: You need to include the moment jquery file also: '{{ moment.include_jquery() }}'.

Comment: Ok ,I'll try it ...because I'm reading the flask web development book ... the author said if I used the bootstrap , that meant I've include the jquery.. So I didn't include it . Anyway I'll have a try ,Thanks .

Comment: It doesn't work.....:(    Is there any place I can see whether moment and jquery worked or not???

Comment: Can you see if it works when you omit 'current_time' from the template?

Comment: You mean like this way?? I tried but it didn't work......<p>The local date and time is {{moment().format('LLL')}}.</p>
<p>That was {{moment().fromNow(refresh=True)}}</p>

Comment: Is that all what is in your `index.html` ?...Did u extend it from `base.html`?

Comment: Thanks a lot .....I didn't involve the extend sentence in the index.html....Now it works !Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `index.html` only contains those two line, which is clearly reflects the output you got on the screen-shot, then you will need to *extend* it from `base.html`:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block title %}Flasky - Home page{% endblock %}

{% block page_content %}
<p>The local date and time is {{moment(current_time).format('LLL')}}.</p>
<p>That was {{moment(current_time).fromNow(refresh=True)}}</p>   
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Ah....Got it , I forgot to add the "extend" in the index.html and didn't use the block........ now it works! Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 2):

I landed on this page as a result of using an old tutorial in which flask extensions were imported as you do above. As such, these imports will not work in flask==1.0.2. I got a similar error to the one you got above. Instead, I would recommend that anyone that lands on this page to use the following:`from flask_bootstrap import Bootstrap` and `from flask_moment import Moment`. Everything else is as mentioned in the other answers. Happy coding.